# Extracting patterns from text in R

Tags: regex, r

My data is like:

```
t <- "The data is like hi hi hi hi  and hi hi end"
```

and my regular expression is:

```
grammer <- "[[:space:]]*(hi)+[[:space:]]"
```

After executing below two lines:

```
res <- gregexpr(grammer, t)
regmatches(t, res)
```

I got output:

```
 [[1]]
 [1] " hi " "hi "  "hi "  "hi "  " hi " "hi "
```

however, I want something like: `" hi hi hi hi "` and `" hi hi "`

Comment: Clearly the fault is in misspelling "grammar."  :-) :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could do like this,

```
> t<-"The data is like hi hi hi hi  and hi hi end"
> grammer<-"[[:space:]]*(hi[[:space:]])+[[:space:]]*"
> res<-gregexpr(grammer, t)
> regmatches(t, res)
[[1]]
[1] " hi hi hi hi  " " hi hi "
```

OR

```
> grammer<-"[[:space:]]*(hi[[:space:]])+"
> res<-gregexpr(grammer, t)
> regmatches(t, res)
[[1]]
[1] " hi hi hi hi " " hi hi "
```

OR

```
> t <- "The data is like hi hi hi hi and hi hi end hi"
> grammer<-"[[:space:]]*(hi\\>[[:space:]]?)+"
> res<-gregexpr(grammer, t)
> regmatches(t, res)
[[1]]
[1] " hi hi hi hi " " hi hi "       " hi"
```

Without leading or following spaces.

```
> t <- "The data is like hi hi hi hi and hi hi end hi"
> grammer<-"hi\\>([[:space:]]hi)*"
> res<-gregexpr(grammer, t)
> regmatches(t, res)
[[1]]
[1] "hi hi hi hi" "hi hi"       "hi"
```

**Explanation:**

- `[[:space:]]*` Matches a space character zero or more times.
- `(hi[[:space:]])+` Matches the string `hi` and the following space one or more times.

Comment: Thanks Avinash but if my data is like -> "The data is like hi hi hi hi  and hi hi end hi." What can I do for such conditions

Comment: @jay_phate what's your expected output for the above?

Comment: The output should be -> "hi hi hi hi" ,"hi hi","hi"  So I want these three values

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of "hi\\>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63144/discussion-between-jay-phate-and-avinash-raj).